# Test WP7 prototype directly on the phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, testing, expression-blend, sketchflow

I created a low-fidelity prototype for an app for WP7. This was done in Expression Blend + Sketchflow using Sketchflow WP7 template from http://wp7sketchflow.codeplex.com/

While this worked out fine, I now need to test the prototype - I guess the best way to  do so would be to run it on an actual device. Is there a way to (easily!) move the whole thing to WP7 project, build it and deploy to WP7 device?

I want to avoid having to test the prototype on a PC with a mouse...

Thx for any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, sorry. However I think you can use [SketchFlow player](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee341402%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) on PC and avoid testing with mouse if you have touch monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Pol is right, I tried it as well and there is still no way for WP7 prototypes. However if you have a WPF prototype you can convert it to a normal app:

https://www.intertech.com/Blog/post/Packaging-a-SketchFlow-Prototype-%28and-moving-to-production%29.aspx

Maybe this is helpful for someone who doesn't do a phone application.